# bind function sample has an error in the book of You-Dont-Know-JS

Tags: javascript

From the [link](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md) , There is a piece of code:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== "function") {
        // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
        // internal IsCallable function
        throw new TypeError( "Function.prototype.bind - what " +
            "is trying to be bound is not callable"
        );
    }

    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP = function(){},
        fBound = function(){
            return fToBind.apply(
                (
                    this instanceof fNOP &&
                    oThis ? this : oThis
                ),
                aArgs.concat( Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ) )
            );
        }
        ;

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
};


function foo(p1,p2) {
    this.val = p1 + p2;
}

// using `null` here because we don't care about
// the `this` hard-binding in this scenario, and
// it will be overridden by the `new` call anyway!
var bar = foo.bind( null, "p1" );

var baz = new bar( "p2" );

console.log(baz.val); // p1p2
```

I run this this piece of code in Chrome. I got the output of 'undenfined', not the answer of 'p1p2' listed in the book

I find, pass the *null* to the bind function is not correct. When *null* is passed in, **this** at the line of code 'this.val = p1 + p2;' is equal to '*window*', not the baz object.

But, if I use the builtin function of bind, the output is correct.
I think the piece of code convey huge misunderstandings.

Could anyone please give me more clarification?

Comment: look at the polyfill (which you don't need in chrome anyway) at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind to see the difference between working code and non-working

Comment: that link says `Here is the (slightly reformatted) polyfill provided by the MDN page` - they forgot to mention it's also been changed with that one addition, and the removal of a conditional assignment later ... perhaps that book should be called "we don't know how to copy and paste MDN code"

Comment: Thank you very much. I try to run the polyfill code on MDN page. the not working version has '& oThis', why did the author add '& oThis'?

Comment: may have been there originally, but MDN code works, so use that

Comment: Another question, the correct version on MDN page, has a conditional assignment. commented as "Function.prototype don't have a prototype property". In which condition the conditional assignment will not be executed? as of now, I can't yet find out. could you please help to point out?

Comment: I find a link, for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506149/error-in-mdn-functionbind?rq=1